# Changing the .vertices array in three js geometry

Tags: three.js

I have two `THREE.Points` objects in a three js scene. The scene starts showing all the points in the `points1` object which works perfectly. The issue is that a user can type in a search string into the `search` var using the `dat.gui` library, and I want to show only the points they search for. I am doing this by creating a new vertex array for the `pointsS` geometry and assigning it in my update function. `points` disappears correctly on search, and I know that `pointsS.geometry.vertices` contains the right values, but it never shows them in the scene. Is this kind of update possible? Excerpt from up update loop below.

Thanks!

```
searchVertices = [];
for (let i = 0; i < vertices.length; i++) {
  let particle = vertices[i];
  if (search !== "") {
    let matchStr = particle.name;
    let re = new RegExp(search, 'i');
    if (matchStr.match(re)) {
      searchVertices.push(particle);
    }
  }
}

if (search !== "") {
  pointsS.geometry.vertices = searchVertices;
  points1.visible = false;
} else {
  points1.visible = true;

points1.geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
pointsS.geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
```

Comment: Reassigning the vertices array is not valid three.js code. I expect the approach used in [this](http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_buffergeometry_selective_draw.html) three.js example would be appropriate. That is, use `BufferGeometry` with a `visible` attribute. If you don't care about efficiency, you can just create a new geometry each time, but I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: Thank you. I will try to follow that example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone stumbling upon this in the future, what I ended up doing was hiding the vertices outside the field of view but multiplying them all by a fixed scalar. When I wanted to return them to the view, I multiplied them by the reciprocal.